# Guaranteed Funds from a 9 day trade

Tags: united-states, scams, money-transfer

Has anyone conducted a simple bitcoin trade with a "financial fund manager" where in 7 to 9 days you received a guaranteed 3-5x return on your investment?

1. were there any charges associated with the trading?
2. were there any charges associated with the transfer of funds?
3. were you able to transfer your entire profits or 10k at a time due to banking regulations?

Comment: 100% scam. Stop all contact now.

Comment: If they could guarantee that kind of return, they wouldn't be bothering trying to get you involved. Scam, pure and simple.

Comment: If they could guarantee a 3x return in 7 days, they would not need you to "invest" your money, they would use their own money, as investing even one single dollar would return hundreds of billions in half a year! Just so you can understand the scale of how ludicrously implausible this is.

Comment: No legitimate trading investment guarantees returns. Legitimate investment opportunities will always have disclaimers saying that the investments are not insured by the FDIC and could lose money. No one can guarantee a specific return on trading - it always involves a risk of losing money.